# SquirrelMail Installation Problem

Tags: squirrelmail

I have downloaded squirrelMail from [SquirrelMail Official Website](http://www.squirrelmail.org/download.php), then I uploaded the extracted files to a free hosting account on x10hosting.com.

when I try to connected to the Squirrel Mail, I get the following error

```
Error opening ../data/default_pref
Could not create initial preference file!
/data/ should be writable by user sikas
Please contact your system administrator and report this error.
```

I want to know how to solve this issue and what files exactly should be edited.

PS: I edited the config file but I`m not sure about the values I entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best that you configure SquirrelMail by running the conf.pl script in the config directory. The problem you are dealing with is the result of incorrect permissions.  Both the data directory and the attachment directory need to be writable by the user that the web server runs.  If you do not know what user this is (www, www-data or something else) it chmod them to 1777.

Comment: do I chmod /data/ to 1777 or to 777?? and how can I run config.pl script? (Note: this is a free hosting)

Comment: I prefer 1777. When the sticky bit is set (the 1 in 1777), only the item's owner, the directory's owner, or the superuser can rename or delete files.

Comment: well, I have found another package that worked with me without having to chmod any file it is afterlogic. It is AWESOME!! http://www.afterlogic.com/ ... yet I will mark your question as the answer as you were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It might be that x10hosting.com don't let you use SquirrelMail (anyway, isn't that included in cPanel?).

Have you tried chmodding /data/ to 777?

Comment: I have chmodded /data/ to 777 and all the files included.

Comment: It does exist in the CPanel, yet this is a company website and I won`t give the CPanel info to every employee in the company so I have installed the afterlogic webmail light which suited the company requirements. Thanks.